# Daemon Tools Unable To Add Device

Tags: windows-7

This is happening every time I try to do a registry cleanup. I run **Auslogics BoostSpeed** and after it's done **Daemon Tools Lite** is useless. I fixed it last time by doing a system restore but that's not the solution, registry needs to be cleaned up right? When I open **Daemon Tools Lite** after the cleanup it says:

```
Installing device driver (a windows pop up) and then it says that it failed to 
install the driver.
```

When I try to add virtual devices it says:

```
Unable to add virtual device.
```

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall daemon tools?  Furthermore stop using programs like Auslogics Boostspeed if it causes you so much trouble the program I guarantee does NOT make your system faster it's all just magic fish oil

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled and re-installed. Made no difference.